# Owl carousel responsive 1170px div width issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, ajax

When my display size in less than 1170px owl carousel div width overflow. What am I do?

[image]

```
    jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    "use strict";
    //  TESTIMONIALS CAROUSEL HOOK
    $('#customers-testimonials').owlCarousel({
        loop: true,
        center: true,
        items: 3,
        margin: 0,
        autoplay: true,
        dots:false,
        autoplayTimeout: 8500,
        smartSpeed: 450,
        responsive: {
          0: {
            items: 1
          },
          768: {
            items: 2
          },
          1170: {
            items: 3,
            nav:true
          }
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Probably it caused by `nav:true`, false it and try again.

Answer (score 0):

Try this ! autoWidth true or you modify css!
In js

```
$('.owl-carousel').owlCarousel({
    margin:10,
    loop:true,
    autoWidth:true,
    items:4
})
```

or in css

```
@media screen and (min-width: 480px) {
    body {
        background-color: lightgreen;
    }
}
```